# Heroku gulp deploy

Tags: heroku, gulp

I read all the topic about gulp and heroku but I don't udnerstand what's wrong with my procfile.

When I'm in local launching like that works:
    node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp build

So in the procfile I write:
web: node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp build

as advised here http://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-heroku-using-gulp-node-git/

But still this is not working. No build problem nothing with the heroku log...

Any idea ?