# gulp command in heroku procfile

Tags: heroku, procfile

I have a node.js/express app, I would like to run the command `gulp build` to generate my static assets when deploying with heroku, just before my node command `lcm server`, as I keep my `public` folder in my `.gitignore` file.

I'm having trouble finding how I can run this command during my heroku deployment.

So far my Procfile is:

```
web: lcm server
```

This doesn't seem to work -

```
gulp build
web: lcm server
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386492/heroku-gulp-deploy!

Answer (score 0):

#### Make a Procfile

Begin by making a blank file named `Procfile` and placing it within the root of your project. Procfile is short for “Process File” and used to explicitly declare what command should be executed to start your app. By default, a `Procfile` is not required, but it’s good form for Node-based projects to create one.

If a `Procfile` isn’t defined, then one will be created automatically using npm start as the web process type.

#### Possible solution

Try this one:

```
web: node node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp build
```

The line above lets us use the locally installed version of Gulp provided by Node’s Package Manager (NPM) instead of having to use a globally installed version.

#### Helpful resources

- from https://www.sitepoint.com/deploying-heroku-using-gulp-node-git/